# How to Make reactJS to run on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, iis-8

I am working on a application where I will create Web API in .net and client application using ReactJS. WebAPI and client application both needs to be hosted on IIS. I am trying to host Reactjs examples on IIS but not successful.

I do not want to use reactJS.net as I will have to create a mvc application then.

Has anybody tried hosting on IIS 8.0. is there anything specific we need to do?

Comment: There is nothing special to do to host React on IIS, really.. it's just a simple HTML file + some JS. Also, care to elaborate what you mean by you were not successful to host React on IIS? What was the problem?

Comment: Thats what I thought. I am trying to run examples provided with react0.13.3 by creating virtual directory I get this message 

If you can see this, React is not working right. If you checked out the source from GitHub make sure to run grunt.

but if I just double click on index.html to open it in browser using fileserver, it works correctly.

Comment: Could it be because of any compilation issues of JSX to javascript?

Comment: It was my fault. My virtual directory was pointing to example in inside folder. It should have been pointing to react0.13.3

Comment: If you succeeded, please post your answer. and I have a question. Did you deployed web api and website separately?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do 3 simple steps:

1. Take React js start kit
2. `npm run build` - it will generate the build
3. Open IIS create website and give path to you build folder
4. Then run it